# Turbo C++ Constant Limit

Tags: c

In Turbo  C++ (for C language) the limit of constant values is -32768 to 32767.

But if I am initializing the value more than 32767 or less than -32768 it is showing result.

So how does the compiler gives evaluates result for values more than 32767 and less than -32768.

How does the calculation takes place for these? To what does the extended value change?

Comment: Suggest you quote the compiler manual and show your code to get any help here.

Answer (score 3):

Turbo C++ is a 16-bit compiler, so the constants are 16-bit integers (range -32768..+32767) by default.

You can add an `L` suffix to declare 32-bit constants, and store them in longs, like this:

`const long LARGE_CONSTANT = 100000L;`

The range for 32-bit long integers is -2147483648..+2147483647.

If you omit the `L` suffix or store a large constant as `int` instead of `long`, it will be truncated to 16 bits. That is,

`const int LARGE_CONSTANT = 100000;`

will then imply `LARGE_CONSTANT = -31072` because `-31072` is the (unique) integer *x* such that *x* **mod** 2<sup>16</sup> = 100000 **mod** 2<sup>16</sup>.

Comment: The value -32768 for a 16 bit signed int is not explicitly permitted by the standard and will result in implementation-defined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say that you write something like `int i = 40000;` on a 16 bit compiler. The compiler is smart enough to realize that the literal `40000` is actually too large to be an int, so the `40000`literal's type is therefore `long`.

When you try to show a long into an int in C, the long get implicitly converted according to the following rules:

C11 6.3.1.3

> 1 When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it
>   is unchanged.
>
> 2 Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that
>   can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of
>   the new type.
>
> 3 Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an
>   implementation-defined signal is raised.

3) is what applies to `int`, since `int` is signed. Implementation-defined means that different compiler can implement it in different ways. Your compiler must document how this is done.

In practice though, your compiler & CPU use two's complement. So what will happen is that the number `40000`, which equals `0x9C40` on a binary level, simply gets treated as a signed 16 bit int. And according to two's complement, `0x9C40` for a signed 16 gives `-25536`.